# failed in "sudo pip install ggplot"

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Happy new year,

I tried to install the ggplot on my ubuntu 14.04 and got the following error message (code)

my verson of python-dev 2.7.5-5ubuntu3.

I have already did the following

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade gcc
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev

```html
william@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip install ggplot
[sudo] password for william: 
Downloading/unpacking ggplot
  Downloading ggplot-0.6.5.tar.gz (8.4MB): 8.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/ggplot/setup.py) egg_info for package ggplot
    
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ggplot)
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels (from ggplot)
  Downloading statsmodels-0.6.1.tar.gz (7.0MB): 7.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py) egg_info for package statsmodels
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    /tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 449, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 262, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 287, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 618, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 882, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/setup.py", line 251, in <module>
        self._clean_exclude = ["bspline_ext.c",
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/setup.py", line 243, in setup_package
        """Custom distutils command to clean the .so and .pyc files."""
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 432, in generate_config_h
    
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types
    
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types
        if not os.path.exists(src):
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'f2py.1'
    non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

/bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]

 int exp (void);

     ^

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]

 int exp (void);

     ^

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

Running from numpy source directory.

/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 449, in <module>

    **setuptools_kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 262, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 287, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 618, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 882, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

    run_setup(setup_script, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup

    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in run

    return func()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in runner

    _execfile(setup_script, ns)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile

    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/setup.py", line 251, in <module>

    self._clean_exclude = ["bspline_ext.c",

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/setup.py", line 243, in setup_package

    """Custom distutils command to clean the .so and .pyc files."""

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run

    self.run_command("egg_info")

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources

  File "/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 432, in generate_config_h



  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types



  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types

    if not os.path.exists(src):

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'f2py.1'

non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/easy_install-1xuwcszp/numpy-1.9.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels
Storing debug log for failure in /home/william/.pip/pip.log
william@ubuntu:~$
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

This is a common error when you're missing the `python-dev` package. You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Try installing after you have this package.

### Edit:

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734240/948550) mentioned, to get `python-dev` for python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

From the paths in that log, it could be that your pip is installing this for Python 3. `python-dev` won't do in that case, you'd need package `python3-dev` to get `Python.h` for Python 3.